# What Callback url i need to set in my twitter app page for my iOS App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter

I'm trying to implement twitter integration for my iOS app and my apps deployment target is 4.0 & greater, I'm using [bengottlieb sample](https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone) for twitter share, In my twitter app page in Callback URL: text field When I don't set callback url in app settings my app is crashed! (authenticatedWithUsername delegate method is getting called but it is dismissing the view controller)What callback url I must set?I want to return to the app after authorization?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to provide any valid URL at the Settings -> Callback Url.
I have used "https://www.google.com" and my app start working. 
Also, remember to unchecked the Enable Ca Callback Locking